# Two way minecarts on a single track

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built a rail system for some minecarts to transport items from my mineshaft back to my base, with a load/unload system. However what I'm trying to achieve is to get two minecarts working on the same single run of track at the same time.

To achieve this, at the mineshaft end of the track, I'm trying to use detectors to detect an approaching minecart returning after unloading from my base (B), and launch the loading minecart (A), and prevent them from colliding by switching the track at the junctions.

[image: Minecart rail system]

The image above shows the basics. I've used a powered rail under the loading minecart (A), and a detector on the track which powered the powered rail. I've tried all sorts of combinations of junctions (using detectors to switch them), but all my attempts so far have been fruitless. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the order in which you place the tracks and making sure "jumping" a track always happens straight forward. The S pattern is just there to slow the cart down so it doesn't reach the end before the other one departs.

[image: Picture of the situation described above.]

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. You wouldn't believe how long I've spent trying to get this to work. Many thanks.

Comment: Based on your answer, I've made it a little smaller, by removing the S section, the repeater and reducing the number of straight sections from 9 to 5 and moving the redstone circuit closer to the track (left a 1 block between the redstone and the rail).

Comment: ...reducing the number of straights below 5 seems to start causing the carts to collide.

Comment: @Bryan it did have room for improvement, but the important thing is that the idea is understood from it.

Comment: Exactly, I wouldn't have managed it without the concept you provided. Many thanks.

Comment: Unrelated; what on earth is going on with the sideways redstone in your screenshot there?

Comment: @Token some odd glitch

Comment: Any chance you can upload a pic of the improved version?? :D